# Parsing JSON into Google spreadsheet (Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a download in JSON format that I get through the API.
Example:

```
{
    "Employees": [
        {
            "User": {
                "UserId": "4d132227-ea5c-4e57-b105-2f8b97872545",
                "Login": "test@gmail.com",
                "FullName": {
                    "LastName": "Фамилия",
                    "FirstName": "Имя",
                    "MiddleName": "Отчество"
                },
                "IsRegistered": true
            },
            "Permissions": {
                "UserDepartmentId": "b5072e57-1e96-490b-ae03-2fd52ef84a3a",
                "IsAdministrator": false,
                "DocumentAccessLevel": "SelectedDepartments",
                "SelectedDepartmentIds": [
                    "b5072e57-1e96-490b-ae03-2fd52ef84a3a",
                    "cd2e04dc-8d3f-4d63-88fd-f900c496e146",
                    "36e4434b-519d-4e40-9253-3464c10ed83e"
                ],
                "Actions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "CreateDocuments",
                        "IsAllowed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "DeleteRestoreDocuments",
                        "IsAllowed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "SignDocuments",
                        "IsAllowed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "AddResolutions",
                        "IsAllowed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "RequestResolutions",
                        "IsAllowed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "ManageCounteragents",
                        "IsAllowed": false
                    }
                ],
                "AuthorizationPermission": {
                    "IsBlocked": false
                }
            },
            "Position": "Специалист по снабжению",
            "CanBeInvitedForChat": true,
            "CreationTimestamp": {
                "Ticks": 637284074150000000
            }
        }
    ],
    "TotalCount": 214
}
```

An example of what should happen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/updBp.png)

The ratio of the JSON list of employees with columns in the table:

```
A: "User": {"UserId"} - Employee ID
B: "User": {""FullName""} - FULL NAME
C: "Position" - Position
D: "User": {"Login"} - Mail
E: "User": {"IsRegistered"} - Login activated?
F: "Permissions": {"IsAdministrator"} - Administrator?
G: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "SignDocuments","isAllowed": true} - Can sign documents
H: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "AddResolutions","isAllowed": true} - Can coordinate documents
I: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "RequestResolutions","isAllowed": true} - Can request document approval
J: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "CreateDocuments","isAllowed": true} - Can create documents and work with drafts
K: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "DeleteRestoreDocuments","isAllowed": true} - Can delete documents and drafts, restore documents
L: "Permissions": {"Actions": [{"Name": "ManageCounteragents","isAllowed": true} - Can work with a list of counterparties
```

How can I convert JSON to a Google spreadsheet for 300+ rows? At the moment I only have a request to the API. The response is JSON. What are my next steps?

```
function GetEmployees(){

  var DdocAuthKey = GetAuthToken() 
  for (let i = 0; i < boxId.length; i++) {                                                                            
    let url = `https://diadoc-api.kontur.ru/GetEmployees?boxId=`+ boxId[i]                                            
    let options =                                                                                                     
    {
      method: "GET",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      headers: {authorization: "DiadocAuth ddauth_api_client_id=" + DdocAPIkey + `,ddauth_token=` + DdocAuthKey}
    }

    var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
    var obj = JSON.parse(json)

    printValues(obj);enter code here
    }
}

function printValues(obj) {
  for(var k in obj) {
    if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
      printValues(obj[k]);
    } else {
      return obj[k] + "<br>"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All you need is to make a 2d array from the json and put it on the sheet. Have you tried the suggested solution? And it's not clear if there will be one JSON with 300 employees inside or there will be 300 JSONs (and 300 requests respectively, which can excess the time limit for a script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

  // here is your object (parsed json)
  var obj = {
    "Employees": [
      {
        "User": {
          "UserId": "4d132227-ea5c-4e57-b105-2f8b97872545",
          "Login": "test@gmail.com",
          "FullName": {
            "LastName": "Фамилия",
            "FirstName": "Имя",
            "MiddleName": "Отчество"
          },
          "IsRegistered": true
        },
        "Permissions": {
          "UserDepartmentId": "b5072e57-1e96-490b-ae03-2fd52ef84a3a",
          "IsAdministrator": false,
          "DocumentAccessLevel": "SelectedDepartments",
          "SelectedDepartmentIds": [ "b5072e57", "cd2e04dc", "36e4434b" ],
          "Actions": [
            { "Name": "CreateDocuments",        "IsAllowed": true  },
            { "Name": "DeleteRestoreDocuments", "IsAllowed": true  },
            { "Name": "SignDocuments",          "IsAllowed": true  },
            { "Name": "AddResolutions",         "IsAllowed": true  },
            { "Name": "RequestResolutions",     "IsAllowed": true  },
            { "Name": "ManageCounteragents",    "IsAllowed": false }
          ],
          "AuthorizationPermission": { "IsBlocked": false }
        },
        "Position": "Специалист по снабжению",
        "CanBeInvitedForChat": true,
        "CreationTimestamp": { "Ticks": 637284074150000000 }
      }
    ],
    "TotalCount": 214
  };

  var table = []; // it will be the 2d array

  for (var employee of obj.Employees) {

    var {LastName, FirstName, MiddleName} = employee.User.FullName;
    var name = [LastName, FirstName, MiddleName].join(' ');

    var actions = {};
    employee.Permissions.Actions.forEach(a => actions[a.Name] = a.IsAllowed);

    var row = [
      employee.User.UserId,
      name,
      employee.Position,
      employee.User.Login,
      employee.User.IsRegistered,
      employee.Permissions.IsAdministrator,
      actions.SignDocuments,          // Can sign documents
      actions.AddResolutions,         // Can coordinate documents
      actions.RequestResolutions,     // Can request document approval
      actions.CreateDocuments,        // Can create documents and work with drafts
      actions.DeleteRestoreDocuments, // Can delete documents and drafts, restore documents
      actions.ManageCounteragents,    // Can work with a list of counterparties
    ];

    table.push(row); // add the row to the 2d array
  }

  // put the 2d array on the sheet  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(2,1,table.length,table[0].length)
    .setValues(table);

}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks! It looks good!
But I get the following error:

TypeError: obj.Employees is not iterable

Comment: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/tF13Eoa7rbxL)

Comment: This means that your real JSON doesn't look like in your question. Could you show your JSON exactly how it is? In your question the `obj.Employees` is an array `'Employees': [...]`, it's iterable.

Comment: And from your screenshot I assume you're omitted the parsing: `var obj = JSON.parse(json)`. So the `obj` is just a string. You have to parse it first.

Comment: Excellent! It works!

But for some reason, no more than 50 rows are inserted into the table

Comment: Sounds weird. Can it be due the quotas? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas The 'URL Fetch URL length 2 KB' maybe? You can try to save the JSON into a file on Google Drive and look if it really contains all the 300 employees.

Comment: [full JSON: GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nw5eU4-EpBWAmqyRe-cv2UR0OWPcSYSx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Good. Thank you very much for your help! It would have taken me a very long time without you.

Comment: Your JSON (txt) file contains exactly 50 users. There is no the 300 users anywhere.

Comment: And one more thing. I see you're making the requests in the loop. But my code will overwrite all the data in the sheet at each iteration of the loop. If you want to combine the tables into one big table it will need additional modifications. Probably to move the variable definition `var table = []` upward -- outside of the loop, and to more the last lines `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,table.length,...` downward -- outside of the loop as well.

Comment: I checked. You're right. These are API restrictions. A maximum of 50 rows is returned. I added a loop that adds the page number and the maximum number of elements (50) in the request. Your code works just fine! Thanks again! Do you want to see the final code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the final version of the code. I hope this will help developers on JS and Apps Script when working with the Diadoc API.

Due to the fact that I have 3 organizations, I need to do an additional cycle:

```
for (let i = 0; i < boxId.length; i++)
```

If necessary, this cycle can be removed.

```
function GetEmployees() {

  clearOrgSheets()

  var DdocAuthKey = GetAuthToken() 

  let options =
    {
      method: "GET",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      headers: {authorization: "DiadocAuth ddauth_api_client_id=" + DdocAPIkey + `,ddauth_token=` + DdocAuthKey}
    }

  for (let i = 0; i < boxId.length; i++) {

    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SheetNames[i])
    let pageNum = 1

    do {                             

      let url = `https://diadoc-api.kontur.ru/GetEmployees?boxId=`+ boxId[i] + `&page=` + pageNum + `&count=50`
      
      pageNum++        
                           

      var obj = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options))

      var table = []; // it will be the 2d array

      for (var employee of obj.Employees) {

        var {LastName, FirstName, MiddleName} = employee.User.FullName;
        var name = [LastName, FirstName, MiddleName].join(' ').trim();

        var actions = {};
        employee.Permissions.Actions.forEach(a => actions[a.Name] = a.IsAllowed);

        var row = 
        [
          employee.User.UserId,
          name,
          employee.Position,
          employee.User.Login,
          employee.User.IsRegistered,
          employee.Permissions.IsAdministrator,
          actions.SignDocuments,          // Can sign documents
          actions.AddResolutions,         // Can coordinate documents
          actions.RequestResolutions,     // Can request document approval
          actions.CreateDocuments,        // Can create documents and work with drafts
          actions.DeleteRestoreDocuments, // Can delete documents and drafts, restore documents
          actions.ManageCounteragents,    // Can work with a list of counterparties
        ];

        table.push(row);
      }

      let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

      try{
      let range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, table.length, table[0].length )
      range.setValues(table);
      } catch (err){
        break
      }
    } while (obj.Employees.length > 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well done. Not sure if I understand if the condition `while (obj.Employees.length > 0)` is optimal way to stop the loop, though. But anyway.